# Why does `openssl ciphers -v eNULL` list `TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256` (and similar)?

Tags: encryption, openssl, ciphers

I hope this question is on-topic:

Learning about the `eNULL` "encryption" and the related warning, I wanted to list all ciphers than *include* `eNULL`:

```
~> openssl ciphers -v eNULL
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA      TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
AECDH-NULL-SHA          TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
NULL-SHA256             TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA384   TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA256   TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-NULL-SHA      TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA384     TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA256     TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA384     TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA256     TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
RSA-PSK-NULL-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-NULL-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
NULL-SHA                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
NULL-MD5                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=None      Mac=MD5 
PSK-NULL-SHA384         TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA384
PSK-NULL-SHA256         TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA256
PSK-NULL-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=None      Mac=SHA1
```

Obviously those lines including `Enc=None` were expected, but not these (they also lack a `NULL` in their names):

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
```

Who can explain, or is it a bug in `openssl`?

I'm using `openssl-1.1.1d-1.46.noarch` and `openssl-1_1-1.1.1d-11.43.1.x86_64` of openSUSE Leap 15.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because OpenSSL handles TLSv1.3 ciphers differently to TLSv1.2 and below.

Basically, the output of the ciphers command will always include the TLSv1.3 ciphers, regardless of the string you provide it. So if you specify a string such as `eNULL` (like you have), or any other one it'll include the TLSv1.3 ciphers as well as the actually relevant ones. For example:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v SEED
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
ADH-SEED-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
SEED-SHA                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
```

If you want to specify the TLSv1.3 ciphers, you have to use the `-ciphersuites` option:

> -ciphersuites val
>
> Sets the list of TLSv1.3 ciphersuites. This list will be combined with any TLSv1.2 and below ciphersuites that have been configured. The format for this list is a simple colon (":") separated list of TLSv1.3 ciphersuite names. By default this value is:
>
> `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`

This is actually documented on the [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html):

> cipherlist
>
> A cipher list of TLSv1.2 and below ciphersuites to convert to a cipher preference list. This list will be combined with any TLSv1.3 ciphersuites that have been configured. If it is not included then the default cipher list will be used. The format is described below.

So while I think it's technically not a bug, it's certainly unexpected (and potentially undesirable) behaviour. I'm not sure exactly why they decided to do it this way (it's mentioned on their [wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/TLS1.3#Ciphersuites) but without much detail), but I'm sure there was a reason.

Comment: Just shows what an incredible mess OpenSSL is.